# mleibman/SlickGrid Adding clear button

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, slickgrid

how to reset search options in mleibman/SlickGrid I want to add a Clear Filter Button.

Just want to know his there any built-in function avaliable or we need to write a custom 
function for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a short version of it working, I tested it as well.

```
// remove the text inside each search input fields
$('.slick-headerrow-column').children().val('');

// empty out all column filters within the columnFilters object & refresh dataview
for (var columnId in columnFilters) {
    columnFilters[columnId] = "";
}
dataView.refresh();
```

The `columnFilters` variable is very important but maybe named differently depending on your code, but if you look at this [Slickgrid Example](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/master/examples/example-header-row.html) you can see that it's defined as `var columnFilters = {};` and then make sure you have this piece of code:

```
$(grid.getHeaderRow()).delegate(":input", "change keyup", function (e) {
  var columnId = $(this).data("columnId");
  if (columnId != null) {
    columnFilters[columnId] = $.trim($(this).val());
    dataView.refresh();
  }
});
```

which is attaching all your inputs to that the object variable `columnFilters`... then only after you can use the code I gave (which is working for me as I tested it)

Comment: Did that work? I did not see you replying anything... a +1 would also be nice :)

Comment: I have tried today.It work fine the but the grid don't refresh any idea

Comment: Hmm there's couple of options.. did you clear your browser cache? But I'm guessing it's problem because you don't have the `columnFilters` variable or you have it in your code named differently. Does Firebug (Firefox extension) give you any javascript errors? I'll edit my answer to where should be found the `columnFilters` var

Answer (score 0):

The answer works, but you may have problems if you have more than one SlickGrid on a page.

```
$('.slick-headerrow-column').children().val('');
```

Will reset all of the filters for all of the grids on the page. Another option is to use:

```
if ($(grid.getHeaderRow())) {
    $(grid.getHeaderRow()).find("input").val("");
}
```

Where `grid` is the name of your SlickGrid component. This will only reset that grid.

The rest of the code:

```
for (var columnId in columnFilters) {
    columnFilters[columnId] = "";
}
```

Works for me!